# LEFT JOIN with GROUP BY with WHERE clause and also with OR in sql

Tags: mysql, sql-server, join

I have 3 tables:
 *Table 1* - "taxonomy_index" where we have 4 columns(Columns are nid,tid,sticky,created)

*Table 2* - "node" where we have 15 columns(columns are nid, vid,type etc... )

*Table 3* - "taxonomy_term_data" where we have 6 columns (columns are tid, vid, name etc..)

I want to join these 3 tables and also there is some condition.

I know the individual queries but i want to set all the queries into one and form one join

*Query 1*

```
SELECT count(*), tid 
FROM taxonomy_index 
GROUP BY tid HAVING COUNT(*) >3
```

This query gives me two values, one is count and other is tid. ie how many times the tid are used .

*Query 2*

```
select * 
from node 
where type='book' OR type='student' 
OR type='teacher' OR type='class';
```

here i will get the node which is associated to these content types.

I want to join 3 tables. In output i want to get how many times each tid used(query 1) and where types(query 2) and get tid name from taxonomy_term_data.

Count, tid,name where for given types

Comment: update your question add  a proper data sample and the expcted  result

Comment: Is it MySQL or SQL Server?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: does node table contain tid? What are you joining on?

Comment: no..... node table didnt contain tid

Comment: what DO you want to join on? For a join, there must be some common ground to be meaningful.

Comment: Node table contain nid, taxonomy_index contain nid and tid, and taxonomy_term_data contain tid.... join based on this....when joining node and taxonomy_index we get type.... when joining taxonomy_term_data with taxonomy_index get count

Comment: Sorry......taxonomy_index get name

Comment: SELECT count(*), t1.tid, [name]
FROM taxonomy_index t1
inner join taxonomy_term_data t3 on t1.tid = t3.tid
inner join node t2 on t1.nid = t2.nid and (type='book' OR type='student' OR type='teacher' OR type='class')
GROUP BY t1.tid, t3.[name] HAVING COUNT(*) >3 Assuming you have a single row for each tid in taxonomy_term_data

Comment: @Raska.............ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '), t1.tid, [name] FROM taxonomy_index t1 inner join taxonomy_term_data t3 on t1.' at line 1

Comment: @Blue Moon, Please remove tag [Sql-Server]...Seems you are using MySql. Sorry...I don't have much MySql syntax knowledge.

Comment: But try this...this shouldn't give a syntax error:-SELECT count(*) as 'count', t1.tid, name
FROM taxonomy_index t1
inner join taxonomy_term_data t3 on t1.tid = t3.tid
inner join node t2 on t1.nid = t2.nid and (type='book' OR type='student' OR type='teacher' OR type='class')
GROUP BY t1.tid, t3.name HAVING COUNT(*) >3

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164598/discussion-between-blue-moon-and-raska).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT distinct t1.TID, t3.name, cntt1.count from taxonomy_index t1 
inner join 
( 
SELECT count(*) as 'count', t1.tid 
FROM taxonomy_index t1 
GROUP BY t1.tid HAVING COUNT(*) >3 
) cntt1 on t1.tid = cntt1.tid 
inner join node t2 on t1.nid = t2.nid and (type='book' OR type='student' OR 
type='teacher' OR type='class') 
inner join taxonomy_term_data t3 on t1.tid = t3.tid
```

Comment: cntt1... what is it mean?

Comment: i didnt understand this "cntt1.tid"

Comment: @Blue Moon, cntt1 is just an alias for table result of Subquery which returns you all tids having count() > 3

Answer (score 5):

Ok, suppose you can join on tid each time, you could possibly use the following syntax. Note that the CTE is not compulsary here, I just find them useful for readability.

```
;WITH CTE_Count AS 
 (
 SELECT count(*) AS Count, tid 
 FROM taxonomy_index 
 GROUP BY tid HAVING COUNT(*) >3
 )

, CTE_Node AS 
 (select * 
  from node 
  where type='book' OR type='student' 
  OR type='teacher' OR type='class' )

 , CTE_TermData AS 
 (SELECT * FROM taxonomy_term_data)

 SELECT CC.tid, CC.Count, CN.Node, CT.tid_Name
 FROM CTE_Count AS CC
 INNER JOIN CTE_Node AS CN ON CN.tid = CC.tid
 INNER JOIN CTE_TermData AS CT ON CT.tid = CC.tid
```

Comment: Sorry i didnt understand the CTE...What is CTE?

Comment: CTE is a common table expression. It's just a syntactical way to break up some logic. It has different use cases, but here I create some query's that I join later on.

Comment: Whether i want to add CTE here ?